# Area of Rectangle stretched from corners?

Tags: area, rectangles

If the corners of a 3-inch by 4-inch rectangular photograph were stretched uniformly by 1.5-inch, what would be the area in square inches, of the enlarged rectangular photograph?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to explain a little bit how you tried to solve it, so other people could help you better. Good luck!

Comment: What does lengthened "at the corner points" mean?